# Convert Earth Coordinate to Local Coordinate after Trilateration

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, trilateration

I have done coding of Trilateration following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813615/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances) example and it was really very helpful. One small help I need is. The results (X, Y, Z) returned here are based in Earth Coordinate Systems. I need to convert it into local coordinate system to place it in a map. I have found some suggestion of converting to local coordinate from lat long(For example : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369512/converting-longitude-latitude-to-x-y-on-a-map-with-calibration-points)). But I was just wondering is it possible to change the coordinate directly from the Earth coordinate system?

Comment: You'll have specify the map's [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection), for example [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system)..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming your local coordinates are East, North, Up (ENU):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system#From_ECEF_to_ENU