# Converting Longitude & Latitude to X Y on a map given a certain region

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coordinates, geocoding, latitude-longitude

For a project we have created an SVG map of certain regions in a province in the Netherlands.
On this region we want to show certain points of interests of which we have longitude/latitude coordinates (in decimals).

My question is as follows: how do we calculate the x/y coordinates of a POI given the longitude/latitude, if we are only interested in a certain region?

We are only interested in mapping values from a certain range (longitude is between 51.39 and 51.52, latitude is between 5.4 and 5.6) to a specific map size (675x350 pixels).

**Note**
I *have* found the following question: [Converting Longitude & Latitude to X Y on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369512/converting-longitude-latitude-to-x-y-on-a-map-with-calibration-points)
with an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900420/2814830) but this assumes we want to show the whole world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have fully understood https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369568/2375207 answer.

Define your North-West corner of the location on map:
51.5 °N, 5.4 °E
This corresponds to the top-left corner of the picture, let's say 
x=0, y=0

Similarly with the South-East corner:
51.39 °N, 5.6 °E
x=675, y=350

And just cross-multiplicate using the boundaries:

675 pixels <-> 5.6 - 5.4 = 0.2° longitude
350 pixels <-> 51.52 - 51.39 = 0.13° latitude

Comment: The inclusion of an example make that answer a lot clearer. Thanks!