# Converting x,y coodinates from meters unit to proper unit for plotting purpose

Tags: geometry, mapping, geospatial

I am not very good in Maths so please accept my apology in advance. I have point_x and point_y coordinates which has unit 'meters' coordinates system and data looks like as follow:

```
Point_x     Point_y
1393427.246     4916767.201
1404938.962     4914923.079
1408257.588     4919262.785
1408578.911     4919268.221
1393367.994     4916913.063
1405745.535     4918565.383
1404544.502     4915702.339
1415210.388     4923001.518
1408309.682     4919617.785
1413830.141     4923060.024
1403506.74      4919101.903
1403898.004     4918221.265
1407236.984     4920485.674
1404360.046     4917812.396
1403262.267     4918450.047
1413788.987     4923072.168
1415105.556     4922993.073
1404331.45      4915868.449
1405317.606     4914014.232
1408775.876     4919359.098
1407116.939     4920413.94
```

I tried to plot into Power BI but the map did not show any data point. When I made some investigation I found that the above-mentioned coordinates should be converted into proper latitude and longitude. In fact someone pointed to the existing thread of stack overflow ([Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates)). When I looked at the thread, I found that in the formula, they used value of R (which is radius of the earth ) 6371 km. As the value of R is in km and above-mentioned data points in meters. My question is do I need to convert R into meters? Secondly, my understanding is that as my data points are already in decimal representation so I don't need to convert those points. Could anyone correct me if I am mistaken?

Comment: About the `R`, yes. Generally, in a formula, all scalars of same quantity should be in same units, unless the unit of each scalar is explicitly specified.

Comment: But about the post you mentioned, are you sure that it is the conversion you need? That pages is about converting lat-lon to/from "Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) with the origin at the center of the earth". I think you need something more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369512/converting-longitude-latitude-to-x-y-on-a-map-with-calibration-points).

Comment: @saastn To be honest, I am not sure. I looked at the thread you mentioned above. Point_x and Point_y are the coordinates not the size of any images. Moreover I dont have lat and long values. Could you please guide me?

Comment: In conversion that you mentioned, points are located in 3D space. So if you want to use that, you need to add some z values, probably 0s. But in an  R3 coordinate system, like the one described in that post, points with z=0 are all located on a 3d plane that crosses the equator. Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16271669/2093077) describes better the problem.